# ReactJS - Error Message: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is an error message:

> React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for
>   built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)
>   but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from
>   the file it's defined in.

The error is pointing to this code line:

```
 <CSSTransitionGroup {...fadeAnimation}>
```

The complete Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { CSSTransitionGroup } from 'react-transition-group';

const URL_TEAMS = "http://localhost:3001/teams";

const fadeAnimation = {
  transitionName:"fade",
  transitionAppear:true,
  transitionAppearTimeout:500,
  transitionEnter:true,
  transitionEnterTimeout:500,
  transitionLeave:true,
  transitionLeaveTimeout:500
}

class Teams extends Component {
    constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        teams:[],
        filtered:[],
        keyword:''
    }
}

componentDidMount(){
  fetch(URL_TEAMS,{method: 'GET'})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
    this.setState({
      teams:json,
      filtered:json
    })
  })
}

rendeList = ({filtered}) =>{
  return filtered.map((item) => {
    return(
      <Link to={`/team/${item.name}`} key={item.id} 
      className="team_item">
        <img alt={item.name} src={`/images/teams/${item.logo}`}/>
      </Link> 
    ) 
  })
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="teams_component">
          <div className="teams_input">
            <input type="text"
                   placeholder="Search for a team"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="teams_container">
             <CSSTransitionGroup {...fadeAnimation}>
               {this.rendeList(this.state)}              
             </CSSTransitionGroup>
           </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Teams;
```

Comment: Just a side question. Why are you passing `this.state` as a parameter to your method?

Comment: It is an exercise from a course that taught me how to do it this way and I'm a beginer with this tecnology so I don't know about the reason why the instructor did this way and I don't know which solucion is better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [react-transition-group migration guide](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group/blob/c137382c12c21b775cc0dc65787e00fd2ceff296/Migration.md#migration-guide-from-v1-to-v2):

> *A few notes to help with migrating from v1 to v2.*
>
> The `<CSSTransitionGroup>` component has been removed. A
> `<CSSTransition>` component has been added for use with the new
> `<TransitionGroup>` component to accomplish the same tasks.

This tells us that below line is incorrect:

```
import { CSSTransitionGroup } from 'react-transition-group';
```

You should use new components like below:

```
import CSSTransition from 'react-transition-group/CSSTransition';
import TransitionGroup from 'react-transition-group/TransitionGroup';
```

For more info you can check the [docs for react-transition-group](https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/).

Comment: the latest for v1.x is `import { CSSTransitionGroup } from 'react-transition-group'` ([src](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group/tree/v1-stable#high-level-api-csstransitiongroup))